# Handle tab activate event in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code in HAML:

```
%ul.nav.nav-tabs
  %li.active
    first tab
%ul.nav.nav-tabs
  %li.active
    second tab
```

How do I do something like this I did in jQuery:

```
$('ul.nav.nav-tabs').on('tabsactivate', myFunction);
```

Which selector should I use? or how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember my own question, hehe.

But I think I was referring to:

```
$('a[data-toggle=tab]').on('shown', myFunction)
```